# TFS Devops custom query list items for areas of user

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, devops

Our TFS is set up as follows:

We have different boards (eg. backend, frontend, security, ...)
We have users that belong to multiple boards (eg. Mark can work on items of the backend and the security)

Is it possible that we create a custom query that lists all of the work items that belong to those boards that Marks belongs to.
In other words, a query that lists work items that belong to board x and y (based on the logged in user)

I've already checked the custom query parameters, and the closest i've found is "Area path" that belongs to @TeamAreas.
But you need to provide a fixed parameter for that.

https://ibb.co/GMvRnc1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We have different boards (eg. backend, frontend, security, ...) We
>   have users that belong to multiple boards (eg. Mark can work on items
>   of the backend and the security).

You could use the concept of **team** to define backend, frontend ,security. Then assign different users to corresponding team.

Then you can add **area paths** to support teams and to group work items based on product, feature, or business areas. Then, define area paths at the project level and assign them to a team under the team configuration. You can also create a hierarchy of area paths to support subcategories within categories.

More details you could refer this official-- [Define area paths and assign to a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)

According to your description, some users may belong to multiple boards/multiple teams.

Then you just need to add an `or` filter= another area path in your custom query, just as below screenshot:

[image]